# rsync {braces} fail?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sync, rsync

I need some help in this issue:

I want sync **/path/first/** with **/path/second**/, **/path/third/** ..etc

so I've tried this:

```
rsync -rv /path/first/ /path/{second,third,fourth}/
```

But it worked only for last directory. What's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Those braces are NOT interpreted by `rsync` but by the shell.

Answer (score 1):

`rsync` only takes one target. Use a for loop instead.

```
for dest in {second,third,fourth}
do
  rsync -rv /path/first/ /path/"$dest"/
done
```

Answer (score -1):

How about it?

```
for qw in `ls -d /path/*`; do  rsync -rv /path/first /path/$qw; done
```

Comment: I count 3 bugs. 4, if you want to be picky.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: First you should never attempt to loop `ls` output with `for`. Your script breaks if any of the folders contains a space in their path. Also you need to quote the variable for similar reasons. Pipe `find … -print0` through `while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do … "$file"; done`, or so to be safe.